# Git - deleting last commit (History rewriting)

Tags: git, github

The question is about history rewriting: deleting last commit
(this question is rather how to do that, without discussing is it bad or good)
So, imagine the last commit's SHA is "dd61ab32". 
Remote and local are synced and we execute following commands to undo last commit:

```
$ git push origin +dd61ab32^:master
$ git reset HEAD^ --hard
$ git push -f origin master
```

The first one, as I understand, will erase last commit at remote.
The second one, will reset the local working to the previous local commit, (--hard will completely erase all changes, --soft will undo last commit, but changes will be saved as unstaged)
But what does the third command do? I understand that it does important thing, because without it, something is screwed up.

Could you tell me what does the last , third command do?

UPD:

Thank you, for your answers. It's still unclear. I have extra question, Doesn't the first command make the current HEAD at remote to the previous one?  The explanation "it being invalid". Ok, I will try to explain, which answer do I need. I mean, when I do first command , I can see visually see, what's happened. The same thing applies to the second command. But third command is different, because it's important, but I can't see visually why it's important. It looks like redundant. Can you describe with even more details?

Comment: `-f
--force Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. Also, when --force-with-lease option is used, the command refuses to update a remote ref whose current value does not match what is expected.

This flag disables these checks, and can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.` from the man page https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to read about refs. Without this, I can hardly understand the question.

Comment: The third command also "deletes" the previous commit from the remote. IMO, this is the preferable way to do this since it does not require knowledge of the SHA hash of the previous commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you say, the last command is redundant. This however is not exactly the ideal way to do it. Git should always be about making changes in the local and then pushing it to remote(unless you are pulling someone else's changes) So the correct sequence of commands would be:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f origin master
```

This is assuming the HEAD was pointing at the last commit in master.

Comment: Interesting. Let me check to be assure in correctness of this sequence. Actually I found those three steps here: http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html

Answer (score 0):

When you push changes to the remote, you can only push commits that are descendants of its current head. If you remove or change commits locally after you have synced with the remote, you can't push these changes. However, the `-f` flag of `git push` tells git to push the commit despite it normally being invalid.

The reason why git works like this, is that if you rewrite the history of a git repository, users that have synced with the old commit will have problems pulling from the remote after the history has been rewritten. Thus you should only do this if you are 100% sure that no one else has pulled the commit that is deleted or altered before you have pushed the new one.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. The second paragraph is pretty clear, rationale of this action. But I have extra question, Doesn't the first command make the current HEAD at remote to the previous one? It's still unclear. The explanation "it being invalid". Ok, I will try to explain, which answer do I need. I mean, when I do first command , I can see visually see, what's happened. The same thing applies to the second command. But third command is different, because it's important, but I can't see visually why it's important. It looks like redundant. Can you describe with even more details?